# How can i convert String Vertex to Integer vertex in Breadth First Search in Java

Tags: java, hashtable, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to get data from a txt file and create a graph. But I can't do this because vertex1 and vertex2 are String values.

for example

Vertex1 - Vertex2 - Edges

John Lisa 4
...

As I understand it, in order to write this Breadth First Search method, I need to save the String values in a hash table but I can't because I need integer values. How can I do it ?

Comment: Who says you can't use `String` values in `HashMap`?

Comment: I tried, but I got an error that it must always be an integer value

Comment: Share the code, that's how we can help.

Comment: There's nothing related to BSF algorithm and `HashMap` in your question. Please [improve it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73403290/edit) - share your **attempt**.

Answer (score 2):

Meant is mapping names to a counter.

```
private final Map<String, Integer> vertexIdsByName = new HashMap<>();

public int getVertexId(String name) {
    return vertexIdsByName.computeIfAbsent(name,
            nm -> vertexIdsByName.size() + 1);
}
```

The above translates vertex names to an integer ID, 1, 2, 3, ...

If the asked vertex name already is present, its ID is returned, otherwise a new ID, the number of elements in the HashMap + 1 is stored as the new ID and returned.